# How to write a test for a method which is filtering elements from an array based on string criteria

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, tdd

I have a `Car` class with a category field which is `String`:

```
public class Car {

     private String category;

     public Car(String category) {
         this.category = category;
     }

     public String getCategory() {
         return category;
     }

     public void setCategory(String category) {
         this.category = category;
     }
}
```

And I have this method which is filtering out elements from array based on `String` using the `contains()` method to keep only sport cars. I know this is bad idea, just trying to write my very first unit test. Can you please help me to understand where to start. In general what are the best practices for testing loop filtering logic.

```
private List<Car> filterOutEverythingExceptSportCars(List<Car> cars) {
    List<Car> filteredCarsList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++) {
        if (cars.get(i).getCategory().contains("sport")) {
            filteredCarsList.add(cars.get(i));
        }
    }
    return filteredCarsList;
}
```

Comment: Please note that while the method title suggests to me that you want to keep the sports cars in the list, the code filters out all sports cars (and keeps the rest).

Comment: Yeah, bad naming, thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: Actually, from your description above it seems to me that the name is correct, but the code does the opposite of what you want. I believe you should get rid of the ! operator.

Comment: Yeah, edited it to avoid confusion, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to make your method testable. In your implementation it's a private instance method. Since you're not using anything else from the instance, you could make it a package-private static method:

```
static List<Car> filterOutEverythingExceptSportCars(List<Car> cars) {
    List<Car> filteredCarsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Car car: cars) {
        if (!car.getCategory().contains("sport")) {
            filteredCarsList.add(car);
        }
    }
    return filteredCarsList;
}
```

Now you can easily write a unit test with input and output lists to be compared:

```
@Test
public static void testFilterOutEverythingExceptSportCars() {
    List<Car> cars = ...;
    List<Car> actual = filterOutEverythingExceptSportCars(cars);
    List<Car> expected = ...;
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

You only need to statically import the `filterOutEverythingExceptSportCars` method and have the test class in the same package as the implementation.

Please note that the improvement of the for-loop is up to you to apply and not mandatory. I Also didn't change the naming or if-condition to match. Just write your tests and iterate over your implementation until you like it best...

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Stream and use filter operator like this.

```
private static List<Car> filterOutSportCars(List<Car> cars) {
   return cars.stream().filter(car -> !car.category.contains("sport")).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Comment: This is a nice shortcut, thank you, but I was asking how to write a test for this method.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. You can write give test as above answer using assertEquals(expected, actual);

Answer (score 0):

Just test the contract - if you put in `<something>`, then what do you expect back? For example, what happens if I call `filterOutEverythingExceptSportsCars(null)`, or `filterOutEverythingExceptSportsCars(Collections.emptyList())`, or `filterOutEverythingExceptSportsCars(Arrays.asList(car1, null, car2))`, etc.

Then construct your tests around this series of preconditions, actions and expected results. So your first test may be:

```
@Test
givenListOfCarsIsNull_whenFilteringOutEverythingExceptSportsCars_thenReturnEmptyList() {
    final List<Car> in = null; //precondition
    final List<Car> out = filterOutEverythingExceptSportsCars(in); //calling the method
    assertTrue(out.isEmpty()); //verifying expected output
}
```

If you expect back an empty list in this scenario. You may instead expect an Exception to be thrown, or something else.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how do you get a reference for the method `filterOutEverythingExceptSportsCars()` and call it inside a test class?

Comment: If it isn't `static` then you'll need to create an instance of whatever class it's in. Its access level will also need to be, at the very least, `package-private` and not `private` for it to be directly testable.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to give [kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/) (which compiles to java byte-code) a try:

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class Car(var category: String)

fun sportCars(list: List<Car>) = list.filter { it.category.contains("sport") }

class CarTests {
    @Test
    fun `one ferrari and one truck`() {
        val ferrari = Car("ferrarisportcar")
        val truck = Car("truck")

        val sportCars = sportCars(listOf(ferrari, truck))

        assertThat(sportCars).containsOnly(ferrari)
    }
}
```

You can mix kotlin and java. So an option might be to use java for production code and kotlin for test code.